# How to stabilise the camera when it follows a curve path ? It is shaking when it follows the curve path

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

How to stabilise the camera when it follows a curve path ? Camera is shaking when it follows the curve path

Comment: As by default camera is not shaking when following a path, then it's something with your settings. Please post some screenshots of setup, a gif animation of "shaking", a .blend file.. Check if there aren't any keyframes on camera.

Comment: Increase the resolution for the curve or add more subdivisions. Your question contains very little useful information. The best way to get help is by including images that show the settings you are using and uploading the file so that other people can asses your problem.

Comment: How can I subdivise my curve ?

Comment: See the answers in the duplicate question